# Annuity with payments X, 2X, X, 2X, ...

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I am working on the following problem that involves annuity.

> On January 1, 1999, Biff purchases an annuity for 54700 dollars. The
>   annuity makes annual payments of the form X, 2X, X, 2X, … with the first
>   payment coming on January 1, 2000, and the final payment coming on
>   January 1, 2040. Assuming an effective rate of 8.5 percent, what is X?

I started solving this problem like this:
$$
X\cdot(s_\overline{41|}+s_\overline{20|})=54,700
$$
$$
X\cdot(\frac{1.085^{41}-1}{0.085}+\frac{1.085^{20}-1}{0.085})=54,700
$$
Then, solving for X I got
$$
X=147.761
$$

I also tried to solve it like this:
$$
X\cdot(s_\overline{21|}+2s_\overline{20|})=54,700
$$
$$
X=364.077
$$
Then I tried to use $a_\overline{n|}$ instead of $s_\overline{n|}$ and $s_\overline{40|}$ instead of $s_\overline{41|}$.
But WebWork says neither of the answers that I got is correct.
Can I have some help?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the correct answer?

Comment: Or maybe some options are provided.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I am asking help to figure it out

Comment: Diana, did you get my answer below? Any more questions?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I got it. Thank you very much, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that payments are made once a year (not: monthly!) on 01. January.

Observe the first payment in the year 2000 is X, and  the last payment in the year 2040 is again X.

Let $n$ be the number of two-year periods. On 2. January 2000, you have $a_0 = 54,700 \cdot  1.085 - X$. Then you have the recursion $a_{n+1} = (a_n \cdot  1.085 - 2 X) \cdot 1.085 - X $. This recursion occurs 20 times. Let's compute $a_{20}$ with  $a_{n+1} = a_n \cdot  1.085^2 - (2 \cdot 1.085+1) X $ which gives

$$
a_{20} = - (2 \cdot 1.085+1) X +  1.085^2 \cdot a_{19} =  \\
- (2 \cdot 1.085+1) X (1 +  1.085^2 + 1.085^4 + \cdots + 1.085^{2\cdot 19}) + 1.085^{2\cdot20} a_0 = \\
- (2 \cdot 1.085+1) X \frac{1-1.085^{2\cdot 20}}{1 -  1.085^2}+ 1.085^{2\cdot20} a_0 
$$
and finally 
$$
0 = a_{20} = 
- (2 \cdot 1.085+1) X \frac{1-1.085^{2\cdot 20}}{1 -  1.085^2}+ 1.085^{2\cdot20} (54,700 \cdot  1.085 - X)
$$
or
$$
X \left[ (2 \cdot 1.085+1)  \frac{1-1.085^{40}}{1 -  1.085^2} +  1.085^{40}  \right] = 1.085^{41} \cdot 54,700 
$$
which solves for 
$X = 3260.53$

For comparison:

- without any interest, we would have $61 \cdot X = 54,700$ or $X \simeq 897$.
- with the given interest rate, paying the full amount $61 \cdot X$ on 01. January 2040  gives $61 \cdot X = 54,700 \cdot 1.085^{41}$ or $X \simeq 25,426$.